# Change NodeJS version on Devilbox?

Tags: node.js, strapi, devilbox

I would run strapi.io on devilbox. This needed NodeJS 14.x.x, but Devilbox give me only version 16.x.x

How can I use the previous version of nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

To degrade the `node.js` version, you can simply define the engine you want to use in the `package.json` of your project.
Example:

```json
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
},
```